# Get User Post if Private

Tags: post-meta

I'd like to display a message when current user's post is set to private. The code below does this, however only works when you are on the actual post page. I'd like for my message to be displayed site wide for the user.

```
<?php

// if post is private and needs to be approved by an admin
if(is_single() && get_post_status() == "private" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "notactive", true) == "1" && (get_the_author_meta('ID') == $userid || current_user_can('level_10'))) {
if(current_user_can('level_10')) {  ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, e.g. what do you mean when you say "return this"? Please edit your question and rephrase the wording so that it's clearer, I think you're assuming we know things about your setup and what you're trying to do that we don't

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems anytime I type on here it seems like I can't speak English. I tried revising it. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JoeLandry so if I understand this correctly, you want a site-wide banner message that `x posts are set to private` of/for the current user? X being the number of posts the user has set to private, of which it only shows to the current user.

Comment: I am not worried about the message itself, I just would like whatever message I do set, to be displayed site wide. You can see the code grabs the current post instead of grabbing user posts.

Comment: That code seems like it would be used in a template file, where are you using that code currently? Howdy_McGee asked a question you didn't really answer. Where do you want this displayed exactly?

Comment: Currently it's in the header file of my theme. That's where I'd like to keep it. I didn't think Howdy-McGee's question warranted an answer because I already have set my message to just say that one or more of his/her posts are private and to contact us. That's all I want. But I'd like the message to be displayed sitewide instead of just being on the particular page.